# popViewController not working if previous controller has uialertcontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, popviewcontroller

I am using alertcontroller with indicator in FirstViewController, and I use `self.dismissViewControllerAnimate` to dismiss it. Then in SecondViewController I use `popViewController` to return to FirstViewController but I can't go back to FirstViewController, although the alertcontroller is being loaded and dismissed.

When I tried to remove the alertcontroller, I was able to return to FirstViewController. But that's not the requirement.

Comment: try `self.removeFromParentViewController()` in place of `self.dismissViewControllerAnimate`, but if you show your code is better to understand your issue!

Comment: i dont know how to paste my code here. but here it is: let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        pending.view.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.color = UIColor.grayColor()
       pending.view.addConstraints(constraints)
        indicator.startAnimating()
        var v: UIViewController = UIViewController()
        v.preferredContentSize = CGRectMake(83,0,100,60).size
        pending.setValue(v, forKey: "contentViewController")
        self.presentViewController(pending, animated: true, completion: nil)
to dismiss it i use self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: @ViTUu self.removeFromFromParentController doesnt dismiss the uialertcontroller.